# Regular Expression - Getting Everything But Last Match

Tags: php, regex

I have the following bit of HTML:

```
<p><a href="http://vimeo.com/13114334" title="Grain & Gram: Nick Sambrato, Printmaker"><img src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/747/476/74747630_200.jpg" alt="Grain & Gram: Nick Sambrato, Printmaker" /></a></p>
<p>Read the full interview with Nick Sambrato, Printmaker here:<br /><br /><a href="http://grainandgram.com/nicksambrato/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">grainandgram.com/nicksambrato/</a></p>
<p>Cast: <a href="http://vimeo.com/grainandgram" style="color: #2786c2; text-decoration: none;">Grain & Gram</a></p>
```

My goal is to isolate the last set of paragraph tags.  I'm trying this by match everything between the paragraph tags. My hope was that I'd get three results and I could manipulate the data.

I tried the following regular expression:

```
<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>
```

It's only matching with the first set of paragraph tags.  How do I get it to match with the first two?

Thanks

**Update:**
I was thinking about this in the wrong way.  I can't always assume that there will be X amount of information before the Cast text that I want.  I can assume that Cast will be the last paragraph pulled, however.  So the revised question:  **How can I match with everything EXCEPT the last paragraph?  In other words, how do I match everything before "<p>Cast:"?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to say you want multiple of those:

`(<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>)*`

Or you can use your original regex and use `preg_match_all`, and pick the last element.

**EDIT RESPONSE**: Howabout `(<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>)*<p>Cast`?

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I was actually thinking about this in the wrong way.  Mind taking a look at the update?